# using regex in .replace() method

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a the `.replace()` method in javascript to convert a serialized array of objects into a simpler serialzed string. Here is my code:

```
b = //string
b = b.replace(/},{/gi, "},cb,,{");
b = b.replace(/}],[{/gi, "},cb,,row,{"); //The error is being thrown for this line
```

When I run this code I am getting an "Unexpected Token /" error for the third line. Why is this? The line is more or less identical to the line above it. Please help me figure this out.

Note: I cant submit a string without the regex as an argument because I need the substring to be replaced more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, the opening `[` is a special character that indicates a character class. Since there isn't a `]` occurring after it, the error occurs.

You simply need to escape the `[` for your regex to work:

```
b = b.replace(/}],\[{/gi, "},cb,,row,{");
```

For the sake of consistency, I wouldn't hesitate to escape the other brace characters since they are special characters as well (but happen to be parsed literally in this context):

```
b = b.replace(/\}\],\[\{/gi, "},cb,,row,{");
```